# Assign value to a specific Column in Datatable using c#

Tags: c#

I have created a datatable and added many columns to it.

When the datatable is empty, i want to assign a value to a specific column.

Like finding the column name in datatable and assign value to it... Is it possible ? Thanks

```
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Question_1", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Answer_1", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Question_2", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Answer_2", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Question_3", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Answer_3", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Question_4", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Answer_4", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Question_5", typeof(string));
        dt_FAQ.Columns.Add("FQ_Answer_5", typeof(string));
```

There is a scenario where i would get only the value that has to be assigned to column "FQ_Answer_1" in the above datatable. In that case, i want to assgn value to that column alone and pass empty string "" to other columns. Possible ?

Comment: You mean create a single row ? post some code

Comment: @RajeshSubramanian Updated my question with code. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

In case of your existing datatable with data inside, you have to iterate through the datatable rows and set values to each column

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt_FAQ.Rows)
{
     dr["FQ_Answer_1"] = "your value";
     dr["FQ_Question_1"] = string.Empty;
     dr["FQ_Question_2"] = string.Empty;
     //.... for all the columns
}
```

To find a particular column you can do:

```
    DataColumn dc = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Where(r => r.ColumnName == "yourname").FirstOrDefault();
   //Or simpler 
    DataColumn dc2 = dt.Columns["yourcol"];
```

EDIT: For new Row:

```
DataRow dr = dt_FAQ.NewRow();
dr["FQ_Answer_1"] = "some value";
dt_FAQ.Rows.Add(dr);
```

This will create a new row with "some value" for column `FQ_Answer1`, all the other remaining columns will have `string.Empty` as default value.

You can check other columns like:

```
string test = dt_FAQ.Rows[0]["FQ_Question_1"].ToString();
```

Here test will contain an empty string.

Comment: How do you assign value to dc2 ? Say if i have created a empty row to my datatable. And note that there is not rows in datatable before. After creating empty row, i want to update just one column with value and leaving rest of the columns empty in that created row. How ?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
 DataRow dr = mydatatable.NewRow();

 dr[0] = 1;                // Assuming that first column is int type
 dr[0] = "someothervalue"; //Assuming that second column is string type
 ..
 ..
 ..
 .. // Repeat for other columns.
 mydatatable.AddRow(dr);
```